# Giving argument to systemd binary

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, systemd, daemon

I am trying to run a systemd service for my binary. The binary expects an argument for --public-ip field, which i supply through `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip`. I did in the following way but the executable is not getting started correctly.

When I checked with `sudo journalctl -f` , i saw that the binary cant see the argument supplied to --public-ip option, so it is hanging in a loop continuously trying. WHen I call the exact same command from the terminal it seems to work.

What am i missing here ?

I am on 20.04 Ubuntu server

```
[Unit]
Description=test node
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=$(whoami)
ExecStart='/my/working/directory/binary --public-ip "$(curl https://ipinfo.io/ip)"'
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd does its own [minimalistic shell-style command line parsing](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) of the contents of `ExecStart=` and other parameters. Command substitution (`$()`) is not supported. You 
need an actual shell to handle `$(curl https://ipinfo.io/ip)`.

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec /my/working/directory/binary --public-ip "$(curl https://ipinfo.io/ip)"'
```

Notes:

- The shell may be able to locate `curl` via the default `$PATH`; if not, then use `/full/path/to/curl` or expand `$PATH`.
- After the shell handles `$()`, it will replace itself with your `binary` thanks to `exec`. This way you can still use `Type=simple` (not `Type=forking`).
- You may find `SyslogIdentifier=foo` useful (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289525/108618)).

Comment: Thanks you for your response. One thing tho , in my case my binary is not a shell script. How should i call it rather than with ' /bin/sh -c ' ?

Comment: @DogusUral What difference does it make? `/bin/sh script` runs a script; `/bin/sh -c whatever` runs a *command*.

Comment: i didnt know that, and it seems to work. Thank you sir you saved my day !